# Unable to read hdf5 files in R from Matlab v7

Tags: r, hdf5, rhdf5

I'm trying to read in .mat files from matlab v7.

I tried the following code, expecting lapply to assign mydata a list containing the data from each file.

```
> library(rhdf5)
> base :: setwd('filepath')
> filenames <- base::list.files(
>    path = ('filepath'), 
>    recursive = TRUE,
>    pattern = "*.mat"
> )
> mydata <- lapply(filenames, function(x) h5read(x))
```

Instead I received the following code:

```
> Error in H5Fopen(file, flags = flags, fapl = fapl, native = native) : 
> HDF5. File accessibilty. Unable to open file.
```

I've also looked at the Bioconducter website, but I can only find solutions for downloaded data, not locally stored data.

Comment: probably a file path issue, but if you've cleared that, maybe you could use the R.matlab package to open the file.

Comment: I tried using the R.matlab package previously, but these files are saved using v7, which is not compatible with R.matlab, hence the rhdf5 package. Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: How about contacting the maintainer of `rhdf5` to see what they have to say about this

Comment: I’ll probably have to do that. Given their history on the website, I’m doubtful that they have a resolution to this issue yet, though. Previously it looks like they didn’t even know what was happening. I’ll contact them and post an update as an answer if I get a response.

Comment: This package  claims success reading hdf5   https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raveio/versions/0.9.0/topics/read_mat    I have not tried it.

Comment: But also --  try the CRAN packages   https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=hdf5r  and `hdf5r.Extra`   .    If those don't work, let's back up and debug.  Make sure that your `filenames` are generated correctly and that they are in the format that `h5read()` or the equivalent in the `hd5fr` package expect.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH!!! The raveio package worked! I appreciate you so much!

Comment: @thefriendly_plague.doctor  Glad that solved it.  Feel free to post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by using a different package called raveio. Posting as an answer in case anyone else is having a similar issue!

```
library(raveio)
base :: setwd("filepath")
filenames <- base::list.files(
  path = ("fiepath"), # Insert your relevant filepath here
  recursive = TRUE,
  pattern = "*.mat"
)
```